# calculate with Jquery each time a input changes

Tags: jquery

I have an application where I have to perform a simple calculation where the price of each item * the amount. I am trying to figure out the best way to do it. I have a input type="number" and I have a item price. I need to update my input fied each time the value of the QTY field changes

```
    $('#add1').click(function () {
    var selected1 = ($('#produceList option:selected').index() - 1);
    myItem1 = pdata[selected1];
    $('#itembox').append('<div id="thep">' + '<p class = "product">' + myItem1.Name + '    ' + myItem1.Price + '</p>' + '<label for="howMAny">Qty:</label>' + '<input id="howMany" type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0">' + '<label for="thisMany">Price:</label>' + '<input type="text" id ="thisMany"readonly>' + '</div>');
```

Comment: you probably want to utilise the .change() function on the qty field. That will allow you to specify some code to run every time the qty field changes. Something like $("#howMany").change( function () { //recalculate here });

Comment: Which element holds the price of the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery's change() function. http://api.jquery.com/change/

The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event can be used with  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onchange` event for this.

This code should handle it when you are using jQueryY

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

Now, instead of alerting the value you can update your result.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code in event below. This will be getting triggered everytime textbox for qty changes.

```
jQuery('#howMany').on('input', function() {
// do your stuff here.
})
```